# Any difference b\w if(raycast....) and raycast alone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there any difference between two codes below :

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position , transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit)){
RaycastHit hit;
targetDistance = hit.distance;
```

```
Physics.Raycast(transform.position , transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit;
.........
```

It is not just a simple declaration , is it? I know if(sth) is just equal to if(sth == true) .However , I don't think it is necessary to use if here .This issue confuses me a lot .Please help with detailed explaination .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: In your first snippet declaring `RaycastHit hit;` after already having `Physics.Raycast(..., out hit)` would be a compiler error ;)

---

[`Physics.Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) returns a bool

> True if the ray intersects with a Collider, otherwise false.

So execution wise of the Raycast itself No! There is no difference ... it is up to you whether you use return values of methods or not ...

**BUT** without the `if` check the value in `hit` might be incomplete/invalid/not set at all and you would get exceptions trying to go on ...

The clue here [`RaycastHit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit.html) is a `struct`! So different to a `class` type **it can not be `null`** but always has some default values.

You can not check e.g.

```
Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out var hit);
if(hit != null) // not possible!
{
   ...
}
```

So while some of the values might indicate it is invalid like `hit.collider` or `hit.gameObject` (basically all reference type properties) others again are structs or other value types themselves so they contain always a value .. which is not valid though like e.g. `hit.point` (would by default be `Vector3.zero`), `hit.distance`(would be default be `0f`) etc (basically all value type properties).

Therefore to be sure you actually have hit something before using the values stored in `hit` you use the `bool` return value to check whether `hit` actually contains valid data or not.

---

Usually always when you use the [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) keyword you let your method return `bool` for indicating whether the `out` parameter was successfully filled or not.

As explanation let's just look at this example (maybe not the best but I couldn't come up with something more explanatory) using `out`:

```
bool FindObject(string name, out GameObject obj)
{
    if(string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        obj = null;
        return false;
    }

    obj = GameObject.Find(name);
    return obj; // true if obj exists
}
```

Now ofcourse you could use something like

```
FindObject("", out var obj);
obj.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
```

but it will always throw an exception!

Therefore you rather want to check whether it actually succeeded

```
if(FindObject("abc", out var obj)
{
    obj.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
}
```

---

Note btw that instead of

```
transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)
```

you should rather simply use

```
transform.forward
```

Comment: May I ask you why and when `transform.forward` is available .How

Comment: @JamesLo allways .. It is the transforms forward vector see [`Transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html)

Comment: Besides, what is  the use of  `out` here ? I just know that it can let the function to return more than more  1 value .Does it enable the function here `Physics.Raycast` to return value  of out var and  other vars .Am I correct ? Please help me

Comment: @JamesLo exactly it allows you to set multiple variables in addition to the return value. `out var hit` is just a shortform of writing `RaycastHit hit; if(PhysicsRaycast(position, direction, out hit){...}`

Comment: sor for asking questions so late , I wnder why you use `out` in your example , `bool FindObject(string name, out GameObject obj)
{
    if(string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
    {
        obj = null;
        return false;
    }

    obj = GameObject.Find(name);
    return obj; // true if obj exists
}   `

Comment: Well in order to demonstrate how `Physics.Raycast` works with the `out` parameter `hit` you used in your question ;) In this example the `return obj;` returns a `bool`, not the `GameObject` reference. The reference is rather provided via the `out` parameter `obj`

Answer (score 1):

From [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html):

public static bool Physics.Raycast(...) will return true if the casted ray intersects a Collider.

So, the inner block in the first version of your code:

```
if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position , transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit)){
RaycastHit hit;
targetDistance = hit.distance;
}
```

will be executed only when the casted Ray hits a Collider.

The second version of your code will always be executed, as there is no condition before.

Anyway, the Ray will be casted in both cases, if this was your question's focus.